# match everything that isn't "hello"

Tags: java, regex

lets say I have

```
String str = "sdahasdahellodsadsahdashellodsadsadsahehllo";
```

and I want to replace every letter that isn't part of hello with the character '_', how would I do it? the output would be something like:

> `_______hello_________hello_____________`

What regex would I have to use? I've used `[^hello]` but it matches each individual character, not the word itself, so I have a bunch of random letters floating about.

Comment: if you mean by my example, it's just more or less how i want the pattern would be, it's not the actual output

Comment: Why regex? You can split the original string on `hello`, then call `replaceAll("_")` on each part, then join each part back on `"hello"`

Comment: @OneCricketeer It's actually not that simple. To account for consecutive `hello`'s, you'd still have to use regex to split on `(?:hello)+`, maintain a list of the actual delimiter (e.g., "hello", "hellohello", etc.), their char count, or hello-count, replace the other chars, and then reconstruct the string. The easiest non-regex solution would be to loop through the chars replacing them one by one and jumping ahead whenever the next 5 chars are a "hello".

Comment: Lets say we want to preserve `aba` in text like `xababax`. What should be result? `_ababa_` or `_aba___` or `___aba_`, or maybe something else?

Answer (score 4):

You may replace:

```
(?:^|\G|(?<=hello))(?!hello).
```

With:

```
_
```

**Breakdown:**

- `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group.

  - `^` - Match starts at the beginning of the string/line,
  - `|` - OR...
  - `\G` - starts immediately following the previous match,
  - `|` - OR...
  - `(?<=hello)` - is immediately preceded by "hello".
- `)` - Close the non-capturing group.
- `(?!hello)` - Not followed by "hello".
- `.` - Any single character (aside from linebreaks).

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yz9Iqo/1)**.

**Java demo:**

```
String input = "sdahasdahellodsadsahdashellodsadsadsahehllo";
String output = input.replaceAll("(?:^|\\G|(?<=hello))(?!hello).", "_");
System.out.println(output);  // ________hello__________hello_______________
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/JLUE47015)**.

Comment: Nice idea. BTW `^` is redundant since in Java `\G` at start represents `^`.